# Nuxt add property to component and access it in the middleware

Tags: javascript, typescript, nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

I'm trying to develop a plugin for oidc-client to work with nuxt because @nuxtjs/auth does not work with my identity provider. Basically everything is working the only problem is that I need to add a custom property to the components and access it in the middleware to check if auth is enabled. I've been looking at another plugins for guidance and this is what I ended up with:

plugins/user-manager.ts

```js
export default (context: Context, inject: Inject) => {
  if (context.ssrContext) return
  const userManager = new UserManager({
    client_id: 'test',
    authority: 'https://ouath.test.net',
    automaticSilentRenew: true,
    response_type: 'code',
    scope: 'openid email phone role user',
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/login/authorize',
    post_logout_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200',
    silent_redirect_uri: window.location.origin + '/silent-refresh.html'
  });
  inject('auth', userManager);
  context.$axios.onRequest(config => {
    return userManager.getUser().then(user => {
      if (user && user.access_token)
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + user?.access_token;

      return config
    });
  });
}
```

middleware/auth.ts

```js
import {Context} from '@nuxt/types';

export default async function (context: Context) {
  if (context.ssrContext) return
  console.log(context)
  if (context.app.auth === false) return
  const user = await context.$auth.getUser()
  if (!user || user.expired) {
    await context.$auth.signinRedirect()
  }
}
```

example component

```js
import axios from "axios"
export default {
  auth: false,
  components: {
  },
  data() {
    return {
      items: [],
      cards: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {

  },
};
```

The problem is that in the middleware the line if (context.app.auth === false) return always returns true because context.app.auth is undefiend, but the component has the auth: false property in it. How can I access the auth property from the middleware?

Comment: Prefer to coercion the booleans aka `!context.app.auth` (`true` if it's _falsy_) rather than `context.app.auth === false`.

Comment: The problem is that context.app.auth is undefined not the if statement @kissu

Comment: Also context.app.auth === false is correct cause I only want too return if the value is explicitly false

Comment: Hi, did my updated answer helped somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following into a middleware to see if a user is logged in or not.

```js
export default async ({ app, store }) => {
  if (!store?.$auth?.$state?.loggedIn) {
    // write something to do if he is not logged in
  }
}
```

Not sure about the `auth: false` part tho. This one is used if you want to bypass the need of auth for something like a `jobs` or `about` page.

---

EDIT, sorry if my answer was not complete enough and if I missed few points. So, here are several points:

- `nuxt/auth` can totally manage any kind of backend auth, you're not stuck with `Auth0, Discord, Facebook, Github, Google, Laravel`, you can use [your own JWT](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/schemes/local) or your [own OAuth 2](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/schemes/oauth2) solution. It is essentially just a helper tool to avoid the managing of middleware's auth state and so on.
- if you're planning on not using `nuxt/auth`, you can ditch `auth: false` because this one is basically saying "do not use the given [nuxt/auth] middleware here", as explained [here](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/guide/middleware)
- you cannot have access to component's data because a middleware is run **before** any component is created as seen in [Nuxt's client side lifecycle](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle#client)
- you can use your own solution and a homemade middleware, but you will be probably better using Vuex and having a global `isLoggedIn` state that you look for
- if you want to use your own custom [named middleware](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/middleware#named-middleware) aka yours named `auth.ts`, you probably need to only write `middleware: 'authenticated'` in your `.vue` component (not sure if TS needs more configuration here)

Comment: I need a way to access the auth property that's defined in component, I'm not currently using the nuxt/auth library cause it doesn't work with my identity provider